# How to start a instance of a SC with PAB and Nami wallet?

Tags: plutus, pab

I am runnin a PAB server in mainnet but now I am struggling to run it with a external wallet (Nami)

I start the instance of the SC with the following command

`curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:9080/api/contract/activate' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --data-raw '{ "caID": "nameOfContract", "caWallet":{"getWalletId":"WhereDoIGetThis?"} }'`

How do I get the walletId of an external Wallet?

Answer (score 1):

`walletId` is an identification of a wallet within PAB, so there is no way to provide it with an id outside the system.

To list you current wallets, run:

```
> curl -H "content-type: application/json" -XPOST \
  -d @testnet/restore-wallet.json \
  localhost:8090/v2/wallets
```